# Is CiviCRM 5.51.1 compatable with Joomla 4.1.5?

Tags: joomla

Joomla is now requiring an upgrade from Joomla 3x to Joomla 4x. 3x will no longer be supported. I'm trying to gather all the infomation possible before I attempt this upgrade. I am currently running CiviCRM 5.51.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/milestones/1#tab-issues it looks like most issues have been dealt with.

You might also get more info in the joomla channel at https://chat.civicrm.org

Comment: Demerit, thank you for the feed back. I see that user permissions is an issue. I may wait as long as possible to upgrade until this issue is resolved. Thanks again! -Keith